# Auto click on page load

Tags: javascript, html, onpageloadstring

The below mentioned code loads a page with a buy the basket button.
Currently i manually click the button to run the code
Can anyone add a auto click the button after the page loads.
I am a total dumb in coding. A fully ready code is required.
Please help.

```
<!-- The basket will be linked to this element's onClick //-->
<button id="custom-button" autofocus >Buy the basket</button>



<!-- Include the plugin //-->
<script src="https://kite.trade/publisher.js?v=3"></script>

<script>
// Only run your custom code once KiteConnect has fully initialised.
// Use KiteConnect.ready() to achieve this.
KiteConnect.ready(function() {
    // Initialize a new Kite instance.
    // You can initialize multiple instances if you need.
    var kite = new KiteConnect("tlhzuxkhbqzcvxrw");

    // Add a stock to the basket
    kite.add({
        "exchange": "NSE",
        "tradingsymbol": "INFY",
        "quantity": 5,
        "transaction_type": "BUY",
        "order_type": "MARKET"
    });


    // Register an (optional) callback.
    kite.finished(function(status, request_token) {
        alert("Finished. Status is " + status);
    });

    // Render the in-built button inside a given target
    kite.renderButton("#default-button");

    // OR, link the basket to any existing element you want
    kite.link("#custom-button");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Where is button's click event?

Answer (score 0):

`$(window).load(function (){ $("#custom-button").click(); });`
Please give click event on page load.